# Google Maps invalid input when adding key

Tags: android, google-maps

I get the md5 certificate fingerprints. When I go to the Google API Console, then create a new android key, I put my md5, a comma, my package name and press generate. I got this error `Your input was invalid`, why?

Comment: Which Google API do you use?

Comment: i don't know , i am new to all this stuff, but i sees that is because they need sha1 not md5, right?

Comment: i want to develop application or android 2.2

Comment: how to get sha1? maybe they key i got is sha1 not md5 , it seems the same way , right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to separate the SHA1 key and the package name with a **semicolon** instead of a comma.

> One SHA1 certificate fingerprint and package name (separated by a
>   semicolon) per line. Example:
>   45:B5:E4:6F:36:AD:0A:98:94:B4:02:66:2B:12:17:F2:56:26:A0:E0;com.example

Comment: how to get teh sha1 certificate fingerprint ?

Comment: What did you do to get the key? What is the result? What does the key *look like* (don't show the entire key)?

Answer (score 2):

You Need to provide your SHA1 fingerprint instead of MD5 fingerprint and your android application package name separated by semicolon.

There is two ways to get your SHA1 and Md5 fingerprint
1.Using Eclipse

```
Select window option and click on preferences.
There is popup widow in which select Android->Build
Here you find your MD5 and SHA1 fingerprint and location of debug.kestore.
```

1. open command prompt and navigate to bin folder where your java installed
   Than use following to get list of fingerprint.

   > keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore

generally for windows your debug.kestore find in
C:\Users\.android directory.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize I was using the MD5 until you mentioned the SHA1 above.